# Remove a tag text style inside span

Tags: html, css

How can I remove the a tag style / link style inside a span?

Code:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg no-border" id="foo">
    <a href="#">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true"></span>foo!
    </a>
</button>
```

Comment: **Warning**: Your HTML is invalid! An `<a>` element is forbidden from appearing inside a `<button>` element! You may get unexpected results!

Comment: "How can I remove the a tag style / link style inside a span" — What specific bits of styling are you talking about?

Comment: This is totally a wrong syntax...

Comment: An empty `<span>`? Is that what you intended to do?

Comment: I think the span is a glyphicon.  So it is an icon

Answer (score 0):

You could remove the "link style" by removing the anchor tag which shouldn't be there anyway..

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg no-border" id="foo">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true"></span>foo!
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your code should look this this:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg no-border" id="foo">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true"></span>foo!
</button>
```

or this:

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg no-border" id="foo">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true"></span>foo!
</a>
```

You cannot put an `a` tag inside a `button`.

If you want to remove the styling of the anchor tag, you can simply target it in your css.  Like so:

```
<style>
    a{
        text-decoration: none;
        /* other styles here */
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="https://account.bbc.com/signin?realm=%2F&clientId=Account&context=

            homepage&ptrt=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.bbc.com%2F&userOrigin=HOMEPAGE_GNL&isCasso=

            false&action=sign-in&redirectUri=https%3A%2F%2Fsession.bbc.com%2Fsession%2F

            callback%3Frealm%3D%2F&service=IdSignInService&nonce=Zme12x2v--if3mplA-
            
            On29KX29BxjLLKWTXY"><img id="signin-image" src="../images-bbc-project/sign-in.PNG" >

            <span id="signin-text" class="decoration">Sign in</span></a>

        </div>
```